# How to count the elapsed nights between two dates?

Tags: php, datetime

I know, how is it possible to calculate the number of the elapsed days:

```
$d1 = new DateTime('2010-01-01 12:01');
$d2 = new DateTime('2010-01-03 18:22');

$diff = $d2->diff($d1);

echo $diff->format('%d days');
```

But how is it possible to count the number of midnights?
The `2010-01-01 22:30` and `2010-01-02 06:30` should result one, because there is one midnight between the two datetime values.

Comment: But there's 2 midnights between `2010-01-01 12:01` and `2010-01-03 18:22`, which is the answer you get; so what exactly is the problem?

Comment: But if I change ot to `2010-01-01 23:01` and `2010-01-03 06:00`, then not

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Easy way: Drop the time and just keep the date:

```
$d1 = new DateTime('2010-01-01 12:01')->setTime(0, 0, 0);
$d2 = new DateTime('2010-01-03 18:22')->setTime(0, 0, 0);

$diff = $d2->diff($d1);
```

This will calculate the days from `$d1`'s midnight to `$d2`'s midnight, in this case `2010-01-01 00:00` to `2010-01-03 00:00`

Comment: Doesn't work for `18-01-2019 16:00` (Friday) and `21-01-2019 08:00` (Monday). Returns 2, correct is 3 (nights).